# Easy way to avoid string addition in php

Tags: php

This question is an extension of the question asked here - [Easy way to avoid string addition in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72800332/easy-way-to-avoid-string-addition-in-c-sharp). I am looking for similar method to achieve in PHP.

Problem: I have couple of string variables that sometimes have text and other times have integers in them. How do I add these variables when they are integers?

Example:

```
<?php

$val1 = "1";
$val2 = "2";
$val3 = "3";
$val4 = "k.A";
$val5 = "k.A";
$val6 = "5";

$total = $val1 + $val2 + $val3 + $val4 + $val5 + $val6;

?>
```

I know the above code will fail because val4 and val5 are strings, what I am looking for is it should avoid adding the above 2 strings and the total should be 11. I can check if the string is an integer or a text but that would take forever if the script I am working on does not have strings as an array. What is the right and easy way to do this?

Comment: @BhanuPratap [not anymore](https://3v4l.org/pOf9I)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution is to add all variables to array.

Then apply filter for each elements checking if it's `is_numeric`

And then just to `array_sum`

```php
$val = [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "k.A",
    "k.A",
    "5",
];

$total = array_sum(array_filter($val, 'is_numeric'));

echo $total; // 11
```

Comment: Yeah I guess I need to add them all to array and do this. Thanks though :)

Comment: Even better than my solution

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use `intval()` function. intval will get an integer value from a variable, if non-numeric characters were found, it will return 0.

Example:

```
$total = intval($val1) + intval($val2) + intval($val3) + intval($val4) + intval($val5) + intval($val6);
// $total = 11
```

Also unless you have hundreds of thousands of values, I don't think it will take more than a few seconds.

Comment: Yeah intval() should work fine for my case, I have less than 10 variables. Thank you :)

Comment: @Vika this method will give you different result than from the other answer. I find the code from the other answer being more correct. Though depends.

Comment: `intval('5.3FOOBAR') === 5`, so that's not really good solution